# SQL-Query in SQL Cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a Website. Some `MYSQL-Queries` take place in there.

If someone updates an field, i want to create a simple "log-system"

like

```
$SQL="UPDATE table_name SET column1=text WHERE id = nr"
msyqli_query($link,$SQL)
```

would be the regular update of a table

for the log i want to do:

```
msyqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table_name2 (column_user, column_query) VALUES ($user, $SQL)")
```

I heard in some cases the Table will execute the query again, if a query is saved to a field.

What could happen in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the query prior to inserting it into `table_name2`.

```
$SQL = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $SQL);
```